# ASP.net Script Service consumption in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, web-services

I have a script service in asp.net and I need to consume this WS from javascript using JSONP (Script tag injection; since it is cross domain, no $.ajax() call).

In this case, where the input to the web method is a complex structure, I have to *create* the input structure at the client. How does matching of the client-side structure to the Server side parameter happen?

> **To make the question a bit more clearer for the unapt answers given
>   :-**
>
> Assume that I have *somehow* created
>   the complex input and passed it to the
>   Script Method. Now, how does the
>   matching/vaidation of my input
>   structure to the input parameter of
>   the Script method happen (or in other
>   words, what is the basis of the
>   matching?)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass complex types to a webservice without using the Microsoft.Ajax framework. I wrote a little example using JQuery.

Assume you have the following C# class used as parameter for the webmethod:

```
namespace JQueryWebServiceTest
{
    public class TwoStringsTogether
    {
        public string StringA;
        public string StringB;
    }
}
```

The webmethod has the following signature:

```
TwoStringsTogether TransformTwoStringsTogether(TwoStringsTogether input)
```

You can call the method like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "TestService.asmx/TransformTwoStringsTogether",
    data:"{" +
        "input: {" +
        "__type: 'JQueryWebServiceTest.TwoStringsTogether'," +
        "StringA: 'HalloA'," +
        "StringB: 'HalloB'" +
        "}" +
    "}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: SuccessCallback
});
```

Note the `__type` parameter, without that it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will sending a JSON structure based on your discovery of the parameters. If it is same as what service accepts then your call will succeed else fail.

Comment: What does this same mean.. thats the whole point of the question!